# Pythonic way to split 3D array in smaller blocks of fixed dimension

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to implement the following routine without using loops, just using Numpy functions or ndarray methods. Here is the code:

```
def split_array_into_blocks( the_array, block_dim, total_blocks_per_row ):

    n_grid = the_array.shape[0]
    res    = np.empty( (n_grid, total_blocks_per_row, total_blocks_per_row, block_dim, 
    block_dim ) )

    for i in range( total_blocks_per_row  ):
        for j in range( total_blocks_per_row ):
        
            subblock          = the_array[ :, block_dim*i:block_dim*(i+1), block_dim*j:block_dim*(j+1) ]   
            res[ :, i,j,:,: ] = subblock 

    return res
```

I have tried with the "reshape" method so that:

```
the_array = the_array.reshape( ( n_grid, total_blocks_per_row, total_blocks_per_row, block_dim, block_dim) )
```

but this seems to change the order of the elements in some way, and the blocks needs to be stored exactly as in the routine. Can anyone provide a way to do this, with a short explanation of why the reshape method gives a different result here? (maybe I am missing using the np.transpose() in addition?)

**EDIT:** I came up with this alternative implementation, but I am still not sure if this is the most efficient way (maybe someone can shed some light here):

```
def split_array_in_blocks( the_array, block_dim, total_blocks_per_row ):
       
    indx   = [ block_dim*j for j in range( 1, total_blocks_per_row ) ] 

    the_array = np.array( [ np.split(  np.split( the_array, indx, axis=1 )[j], indx, axis=-1 ) for j in range( total_blocks_per_row ) ] )
    the_array = np.transpose( the_array, axes=( 2,0,1,3,4 ) )


    return the_array
```

**EXAMPLE:** Here is a minimal working example for the two implementations. What we want is, from  an initial "cube" of dimensions Nx3*MX3*M, decompose into blocks NxMxMx3x3, which are the chunked version of the original block. With the two implementations above, one can check that they give the same result; the question is on how to achieve this in an efficient way (i.e., no loops)

```
import numpy as np


def split_array_in_blocks_2( the_array, block_dim, total_blocks_per_row ):
    
    n_grid = the_array.shape[0]
    res    = np.zeros( (n_grid, total_blocks_per_row, total_blocks_per_row, block_dim, block_dim ), dtype=the_array.dtype )
    
    for i in range( total_blocks_per_row ):
        for j in range( total_blocks_per_row ):            
            subblock          = the_array[ :, block_dim*i:block_dim*(i+1), block_dim*j:block_dim*(j+1) ]   
            res[ :, i,j,:,: ] = subblock 
    
    return res


def split_array_in_blocks( the_array, block_dim, total_blocks_per_row ):
           
    indx   = [ block_dim*j for j in range( 1, total_blocks_per_row ) ] 
    
    the_array = np.array( [ np.split(  np.split( the_array, indx, axis=1 )[j], indx, axis=-1 ) for j in range( total_blocks_per_row ) ] )
    the_array = np.transpose( the_array, axes=( 2,0,1,3,4 ) )
    
    
    return the_array

A = np.random.rand( 1001, 63, 63 )
n = 3
D = 21
from time import time

ts = time()
An = split_array_in_blocks( A, n, D )

t2 = time()

Bn = split_array_in_blocks_2( A, n, D )

t3 = time()
print( t2-ts )
print(t3-t2)
print(np.allclose( An, Bn ))
```

Comment: Could you given an example of what input and output you are expecting?

Comment: I wrote a utility to separate a 3D volume into smaller blocks. You can [find it here](https://github.com/neuronets/nobrainer/blob/be89dd2e6059eaf705177f8f04f51fa1fc971f37/nobrainer/volume.py#L271-L299).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, `np.reshape` should work. While there are different options for the `order` argument, it sounds like you want to reshape the last two axes of length `3M` in the original array both to an array of shape `(M,3)` in the `'C'` order (the default). This can be achieved with

```
A.reshape(A.shape[0], A.shape[1]//3, 3, A.shape[1]//3, 3, order='C')
```

Getting the desired output shape `(N, M, 3, M, 3)` is then a matter of using `np.swapaxes`:

```
reshaped = np.swapaxes(A.reshape(A.shape[0], A.shape[1]//3, 3, A.shape[1]//3, 3, order='C'), axis1=-2, axis2=-3)

np.allclose(reshaped, An)  # This is true
```